# How do I take my tweets OFF private?

Tags: twitter, tweet, retweet

I don't know why but some of my tweets have a lock beside them and people can't retweet them. My accounts *isn't* on private and not all of my tweets have a lock icon. So how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your account isn't set to private, but it's doing that, you'd be best contacting Twitter directly about it. You can open a support ticket [here](https://support.twitter.com/forms).

If you've only recently changed it to private, it might be one of two things, potentially:

- Your account hasn't finished updating and syncing between servers yet.
- Only new Tweets will be unprotected. (I don't know whether this is the case at all. It's just a possibility.)